# XSL check to see if any child node has attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<record>
  <d989 p="Apples" t="Apples"/>
  <d990 p="Oranges" t="Bananas"/>
  <record_group_1>
    <d991 p="Mouse" t="Mouse and Cat"/>
    <d991 p="Dog" t="Dog and Cat"/>
  </record_group_1>
  <record_group_2>
    <d992 />
  </record_group_2>
 ...
```

and I'm using the following XSL template after determining if the node has children:

```
<xsl:template name="hasChildren">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="sectionTitle">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(), '_', ' ')" />
    </td>
  </tr>
 ...
```

How would I wrap the `<xsl:template name="hasChildren">` contents to determine if the node that is in question that has children, that any of the children has the attribute of p.

I'm testing if the current node has an attribute of p with `<xsl:if test="@p">` but I'm not sure how I could find if the node's children has a p.

For the XML example above I would want to ignore `<record_group_2>` because it's children do not contain the attribute of p where as `<record_group_1>` I would want to process.

If you need more clarification let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I'm using the following XSL template after determining if the node
>   has children:

```
<xsl:template name="hasChildren">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="sectionTitle">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(), '_', ' ')" />
        </td>
    </tr>  ...
</xsl:template>
```

**This code doesn't do at all what it is said to do!**

```
I'm testing if the current node has an attribute of `p` with `<xsl:if test="@p">` but I'm not sure how I could find if the node's children has a `p`.
```

**Use**:

```
*[@p]
```

This XPath expression selects any child element (of the current node) that has attribute `p`. When used in a `test` attribute of `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>` the selectied node-set is converted to a boolean: `true()` if the node-set is non-empty and `false()` otherwise.

> For the XML example above I would want to ignore `<record_group_2>`
>   because it's children do not contain the attribute of p where as
>   `<record_group_1>` I would want to process

**Use**: just the above expression.

**Here is a complete and very simple and short transformation** that copies to the output only those children of the top element, that have a `p` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="*[*/@p]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<record>
    <d989 p="Apples" t="Apples"/>
    <d990 p="Oranges" t="Bananas"/>
    <record_group_1>
        <d991 p="Mouse" t="Mouse and Cat"/>
        <d991 p="Dog" t="Dog and Cat"/>
    </record_group_1>
    <record_group_2>
        <d992 />
    </record_group_2>
</record>
```

**the wanted, correct result** (non-top elements that don't have at least one child having a `p` attribute are deleted) **is produced**:

```
<record>
   <record_group_1>
      <d991 p="Mouse" t="Mouse and Cat"/>
      <d991 p="Dog" t="Dog and Cat"/>
   </record_group_1>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
*[starts-with(local-name(), 'record_group_') and *[@p]]
```

...matches all elements whose name starts with `record_group_` and who have a child element with the `p` attribute (`*[@p]`).

It's not clear what *actual* output you're looking for, but the following stylesheet should demonstrate the *general* approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ignore other elements -->
    <xsl:template match="/*/*"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'record_group_') 
                              and *[@p]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<record>
    <record_group_1>
        <d991 p="Mouse" t="Mouse and Cat"/>
        <d991 p="Dog" t="Dog and Cat"/>
    </record_group_1>
</record>
```